# PayPal Express Checkout Error 10005 Transaction ID is not supported

Tags: .net, paypal, express-checkout

I've implemented PayPal Express Checkout using the PayPal .Net SDK

When I invoke DoExpressCheckoutPayment on occasion I'm seeing customers fail payments due to Error 10005 "Option not supported. Transaction ID is not supported."

What is odd is error 10005 is only listed for SetExpressCheckout, but I'm getting this error when the customer is returning to the website from PayPal GetExpressCheckoutDetails is executed, and then they confirm the order and I execute DoExpressCheckoutPayment (and then this error is caught and the payment/order has failed).

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/errors/express-checkout/

I'm not entirely sure what the error means - I assume it's a PayPal payment error and not a code error, and the user can't complete the payment using Express Checkout for some settings/card reason?

Would like to get to the bottom of this, or at least have an answer as to what the cause is.

---

Further to this, I believe this error is due to DoExpressCheckoutPayment being run twice - as in the user has refreshed the page. So payment is successful, but on the second go the error is caught.

Comment: Hi, see you didn't get answer, however for the future maybe try submitting a question to PayPal's tech team @ https://www.paypal-techsupport.com/app/ask